# Comparing raw input to an specific element in an array using Python

Tags: python, arrays, loops

I have a little piece of code in Python where I'm trying to compare a user input to a specific element in an array. Here is the code:

```
movies = ["movie 1", "movie2", "movie3"];

answer = raw_input("What is your guess: ")

    if answer == movies[1]
       then print ("yes that is correct")
       else:
         print ("no that is incorrect")
```

I know the indentation above looks wrong becasue I typed it out in the text box and I'm new to this site as well as python. 
I also know that I probably need to use some sort of conditional loop, maybe a while loop, but I'm having trouble finding where I can compare user input string value to a string value in my array. Any ideas how I might accomplish this?

Comment: You if/else syntax is wrong. You mixed with bash script syntax i think.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. [On topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and ... [the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.  StackOverflow is a knowledge base for *specific* programming problems -- not a design, coding, research, or tutorial resource.  Fix your indentation, review your materials on reading in put, and `print` out variable values to know *exactly* what you're working with.

Comment: If you're not sure whether you need a `while` loop, then review your tutorial on `while` loops to get a feel for what mini-problems they solve.  Review your tutorial on writing an `if`; your program is not syntactically legal in several respects, so this is not yet ready to be a Stack Overflow question.

Comment: I honestly cannot find any help, I've been looking for a while

Answer (score 0):

Have fun with Python! I guess you are trying to make a loop which keeps receiving inputs from user to compare with the desired input until user types the correct input. If so, one way, it can be implemented as following (but think of adding a break condition, like input == "Bored" , to avoid infinite loop and hard stopping your code):

```
movies = ["movie 1", "movie2", "movie3"]
correctAnswer = movies[1]
is_notCorrect = True
while(is_notCorrect):
    answer = raw_input("What is your guess: ")
    if answer == correctAnswer:
       print("Yes, that is correct")
       is_notCorrect = False
    else:
       print("No, that is incorrect")
```

In the code above, when is_notCorrect turns into False. At next condition checking, it will break condition, and done with the loop.

Your code has some issues

```
movies = ["movie 1", "movie2", "movie3"]; # No need the semi-colon in Python

answer = raw_input("What is your guess: ") 
# Need a colon here after if condition, new line, and indent. 
#If you don't like the colon, you need to write a different way with one line of code Eg: <Do A> if <Condition happens> else <Do B> 
if answer == movies[1]     
   then print ("yes that is correct") # No then in if-else statement in Python 
   else:
     print ("no that is incorrect")
```